# Can't change keyboard layout on login screen

Tags: 16.04, lightdm

When the PC wakes from locked state and I try to change keyboard layout on a login screen, it flickers revealing the desktop but the layout isn't changed. Everything worked fine on 15.04. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can fix it, but I know that because I have the same problem. For temporary solution you can do this:

1. Press Alt+Ctrl+F1(or F2, F3, ...)
2. After login type this: `export DISPALY=:0`
3. Type `xdotool type {your password}`

This tools (xdotool) type the required information on X and the problem (for login) can be solved in this way. I hope the Ubuntu team solved this problem permanently!

Answer (score -1):

[this bug on LP](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1245137)

floating bug. He played for many years. There is no solution.

additionally [Fixed a few days ago](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1605012)

Comment: This answer is very unclear. Can you please expand?